# App hanged only in iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am creating an iPhone app with some user authentication screens. I have created these screens in Storyboard. For example, landing screens, sign in screens, Sign up Screens etc.. and made connections between them using model segue. Every things work fine.

The Problem is that the app hangs in my iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1. I have also tested it on 4s, 5 and 5s all with iOS 7.1. In all these devices App works fine and fast without hanging.

Can anyone suggest me why it hangs when i go from one screen to other screen like (Sign In, Sign Up, etc..)  in iPhone 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "hang"? Have you profiled it in Instruments? Have you done anything to get to the roots of the cause?

Comment: Hang like when sign in screen open no operations will performed for some time like will not go back, even not open keyboard, other buttons are also not worked..

Comment: iPhone 4 in iOS 7.1 is litle slow ... Not Hang

Comment: Are you using Google maps' SDK by any chance? I noticed that since iOS7.1 one of my apps is unusable on iPhone 4, the devices gets stuck for several seconds. I switched back to Apple Maps and all is fine.

Comment: yes i am using google map's SDK in this app. @andreamazz Thanks For your reviews.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Google Maps SDK, you could check [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6484).
I encountered the same problem, and in the end I ended up switching to Apple maps, since Gmaps has a tendency to leak memory, for what I witnessed at least...

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4 is a single-core device while all the other iOS7 ready devices are dual-core. Maybe it can't keep up with initializing your view and thats why it lags.

You should try `Time Profiler` from `Instruments` to catch what is too much for a single-core device.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same error when I was trying to launch an UIAlertView in the start of application.

Try  not to launch do anything in main thread before you have set your window key and visible in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
   ... 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I hope this helps